Identify the monitors and show some text or image in windows
I am working on a project where I have to detect all the monitors connected to the system and show some text or image on the specific monitor of the choice. Even the monitor/display is in duplicate screen mode.
So, first I tried to go through the winapi and cpanel lib in Python and prepare the following code to detect the display in both duplicate and extended screen mode.
I am using a Windows 11 OS.
import ctypes

class RECT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('left', ctypes.c_ulong),
        ('top', ctypes.c_ulong),
        ('right', ctypes.c_ulong),
        ('bottom', ctypes.c_ulong)
    ]

    def dump(self):
        return map(int, (self.left, self.top, self.right, self.bottom))

# Define POINTL structure
class POINTL(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ctypes.c_long),
        ("y", ctypes.c_long),
    ]


# Enumerate monitors
def enumerate_monitors():
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

    # Get number of display settings
    num_settings = 0
    while True:
        dev_mode = DEVMODEW()
        dev_mode.dmSize = ctypes.sizeof(dev_mode)
        if not user32.EnumDisplaySettingsW(ctypes.c_void_p(), num_settings, ctypes.byref(dev_mode)):
            break
        num_settings += 1

        # Get monitor handle
        h_monitor = user32.MonitorFromHandle(ctypes.c_void_p())

        # Get monitor rectangle
        rect = ctypes.POINTER(RECT)
        user32.GetMonitorInfoA(h_monitor, ctypes.byref(rect))

        yield h_monitor, rect


# Define DEVMODEW structure
class DEVMODEW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dmDeviceName", ctypes.c_wchar * 32),
        ("dmSpecVersion", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("dmDriverVersion", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("dmSize", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("dmDriverExtra", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("dmFields", ctypes.c_dword),
        ("dmPosition", POINTL),
        ("dmDisplayOrientation", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmDisplayFixedOutput", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmColor", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmDuplex", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmYResolution", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmTTOption", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmCollate", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmFormName", ctypes.c_wchar * 32),
        ("dmLogPixels", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmBitsPerPel", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmPelsWidth", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmPelsHeight", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmDisplayFlags", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmNup", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmDisplayFrequency", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmICMMethod", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmICMIntent", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmMediaType", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmDitherType", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmReserved1", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmReserved2", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmPannableWidth", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmPannableHeight", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmReserved3", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dmReserved4", ctypes.c_int),
    ]

# Display text on a specific monitor
def display_text_on_monitor(h_monitor, text):
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

    # Create a window on the specified monitor
    hwnd = user32.CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        "STATIC",
        text,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        h_monitor,
        ctypes.c_void_p(),
        ctypes.c_void_p(),
        ctypes.c_void_p(),
    )

    # Show window
    user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, 5)


# Handle duplicate monitors
def handle_duplicate_monitors():
    i = 1
    for h_monitor, rect in enumerate_monitors():
        print(f"Monitor {i}:")
        print(f"  Handle: {h_monitor}")
        print(f"  Rectangle: {rect}")
        display_text_on_monitor(h_monitor, f"Hello, Monitor {i}!")
        i += 1


# Usage
handle_duplicate_monitors()

I can able to detact the monitor with winapi or cpanel but it will only detact one monitor if the multimonitor setup is on duplicate display mode.
So, I tried different method but there is no luck.
